# How to Split number with comma after two digit and store into two variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a variable `var Number = 2425;`
I want to break it into two parts and store into into two different variables.

```
var data = 24;
var month = 25;
```

How can I get this in javaScript.

Comment: Is there ever a month > 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coerce the number to a string, and then use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get the relevant characters.

```js
const number = 2425;

const str = String(number);

const data = str.substring(0, 2);
const month = str.substring(2);

console.log(data, month);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to substring the number at target position and after that you can add comma and join the rest of the number . Then split it with comma and get as array. Then you can use the array at position . Check the below solution

```
function splitNumber(number, index) {
    var commaAdded = number.substring(0, index) + ',' + number.substring(index);
    return commaAdded.split(',');
}

console.log(splitNumber('2425', 2));
// ["24", "25"]
```

Now you can use the array index in your variable.

Answer (score 0):

One was would be to convert it into a string and do a slice on it.

```js
let num = 2524;
let strNum = String(num);
let midIndex = Math.floor(strNum.length/2);
let firstHalf = Number(strNum.slice(0,midIndex));
let secondHalf = Number(strNum.slice(midIndex));
console.log(firstHalf);
console.log(secondHalf);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or just math via treating "Number" as an arithmetic progression on order of 100:

```js
var number = 2425
var data = Math.floor(number / 100)
var month = number - (data * 100)

console.log(number)
console.log(data)
console.log(month)

/* Output
2425
24
25
*/
```

But don't really understand how "month" can be more than 12, let alone 11 if base(0).